# I Had a Backdoor Mal Ware on W7. Will it Pass on to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

October 15, 2014, I got hit with a team of revenge hackers. They are working for my ex-father-in-law. He has been proxy stalking me since 2004 but since that has no effect on me anymore, he decided to hire a team of Pro Hackers.

When I say Pro, I mean just exactly like that. When they first hit me, they disabled my firewall. They disabled any type of AV/FW including: Comodo, Kapersky, System Mechanic Pro and Norton.

I had a key scrambler and they disabled that. I had an Anti Keylogger and they disabled that.

Though they cannot hit me as hard as when running W7, I know that as I type every single word, they are watching it in real time and I've only been up and running with Ubuntu, but I'm sure they will find a way to disable that as well.

Their only purpose that I can tell is to monitor me and and keep me off the web. I have on occasion, found some of their hidden files and they talk about keeping tabs for the amount of time each hacker spends so they can get paid.

Frankly, I don't know how my ex father-in-law affords it b/c I fight with them daily. When I say daily, I mean 8-12 hours per day. Another reason I know that it is a team is that I've tried going all day w/o logging in to my PC and I'll wait till about 3:30AM and try to sneak past them, but they must have an alarm b/c w/in minutes they are back in my system, doing redirects and such.

Now here is the crazy part: After I installed W7, I never connected to the Net until I felt like my system was hardened. However, I'll have all my FW rules in place and then work on which services to block and then take a look at my FW again, and low and behold, they have changed my FW Rules and I am not even connected to the Net.

How do they do that? I was not tethered in nor was I using WIFI. As a matter of fact, I had yet to enable WIFI. So that just blows my mind away! But then after finding other files where they are communicating back and forth, they have stuff in there like:

Enable FM Radio
Enable Ham Radio
Enable Blur Tooth
Enable TV

I kinda had a feeling like they were some how or another using radio waves to transmit script and the only way I could stop that was to unplug my PC and take the battery out. Either that, or I would wake up and my PC was not the way I left it, it was set to their 
preferences.

---------->Can anyone explain that to me?<------------------

Once they get a foot in the door, they start executing more scripts and become the SUPER USER and lock me out of programs that I paid for.

I have installed and re-installed Windows over 40 times since October. However, I noticed that every-time I use a Linux based system, they have harder time messing with me. But they have someway or another gained access to my laptop which has the latest version of Ubuntu. The reason I know that they have gained access is that when I was trying to install the latest firewall. (I can't think of the name but it's the one with the shield on it.) As soon as they saw that I was typing in the word "Firewall" they disabled it from the Ubuntu Software Updater. I had to go online and search for it, but instead of downloading it from their site, they demonstrated how it could be installed by using Terminal. I did that, and they could not stop me from doing that.

A lot of people claim that **nix systems are almost hack proof, but that is far from the truth! Even when I've installed Ubuntu just to grab some files for Windows, I would reformat the HD then do a AV/MW check and sure enough there was  Mal Ware in the MBR. The problem is that Comodo does not identify this type of mal ware. It just has an image on the screen and then it allows you to quarantine it. This happens on Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

So the problem is that there is no virus but somewhere in the boot-sector, they have written "self propagation code" THAT EXECUTES AS SOON AS THE DATA BEGINS TO TRANSFER FROM DVD TO THE HD.

How would code that is meant for Windows execute on Ubuntu?

I have spent hundreds of dollars reading books bought from Barnes and Noble as well as paid $300 to have both of my laptops fixed. But all the tech did was flashed the BIOS.

But the PC I'm on now will not let me flash BIOS anymore. I guess they wrote new script to prohibit flashing the BIOS.

I'm raising money to have a Forensic specialist who has a background in law enforcement, but that will cost me $2.5K and the only way to raise the money (I'm on disability) will be to stand at a busy intersection and panhandle. Not the way bums do, I'll have all my receipts and my drop slip from school. I was working on a degree in web design and the hackers hit me half the way through the class and I had to drop b/c of this. I'll also have a copy of a police report that I filed and simply pass out folders with all that info w/ a self addressed envelope complete with a stamp to send funds to a trust account. That way I can pay the forensic specialist and hire an attorney. He said that it would take about three days to do it. All he has to do is place a wire tap and he said for sure that he will catch them, locate them and all I have to do is prosecute them and sue them for damages and lost wages.

I have two websites that I maintain, but can't because I do not want these nitwits to get my password and crash my website. And since I have no fresh content since August 2014, Google has penalized me and I continue to slowly fall from page one of Google for any search term related to my website to page 5 or even lower and some pages that were ranking well, just do not come up in the SERP's anymore.

But back to the problem, how does a program written for W7 transfer to Ubuntu? And that problem is through a back door that they have set up.

I would appreciate any comments on this issue. I'm just now learning Ubuntu and it's fun to play with, but I need to run programs that are not compatible for any Linux off spin.

So until I can get that wiretap on my pc, what can I do?

Regards,

dj

Answer (score 5):

Most Malware that runs within the OS is built for Windows and are in .exe binaries. They physically cannot run on a Linux machine unless they are packaged for Linux machines (.rpm/.deb).

That is not to say viruses don't exist for Linux. [Here are a few dating as far back as 1996.](http://www.unixmen.com/meet-linux-viruses/) Linux's fast updates also pretty quickly patch vulnerabilities, and there has never been a widespread attack on Linux with a program like CryptoLocker.

If Malware has gotten into the MBR record of your hard drive, **use a new one.** Buy a fresh new one, and do not connect it to the old one, no questions asked. If it'd be easier for you, get a whole new computer and just load Ubuntu on it from the get-go.

And you're right about it being harder for "them" to mess with you on Ubuntu, that's because root access works differently in Linux than in Windows. It'll be easy for you to prevent yourself from getting any of the few Linux viruses on Ubuntu if you're smart, i.e. knowing when not to use root.

Simply, Windows programs cannot be natively run on Linux, no questions asked. You need a program like Wine that can execute the binaries, and even then, I believe those programs are somewhat sandboxed. Linux malware is out there, but is far from common and likely will not give you a headache.

[Some further reading on Linux malware.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware)

Comment: Yes, I wrote about that. Last paragraph.

Comment: Sorry! Dumb comment deleted!

Comment: hello @Dr.Doctor. just wanted to point something out... windows programs cant run natively because there is no loader. if someone were to write a COM/PE loader for linux, it would be just as native as ELF files